# Google Nearby Places Api is returning INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-nearby

I am fairly new to Google Maps & Stuff. I am making my Final Yer Project for the degree and facing this issue. I am trying to get the response from the Places Api, I have followed the Official Docs to Construct the URL, but after all the struggle, I am unable to get the result from google. I am using Retrofit2 for getting the result.

I have changed my url by changing Radius. By changing API Key with Browser key (Found a link which suggested this), None of the changes returned result.
My current location on the map is working fine. Help will be really appreciated. Thanks

**Here is my Retrofit API:**

```
public interface GoogleApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET
    Call<Places> getNearByPlaces(@Url String url);
}
```

**RetrofitClient:**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl)
    {
        if (retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**GoogleMapsClass:**

```
public class NearbyBusStand extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    GoogleApiService mService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_bus_stand);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mService = URLEndPoints.getGoogleApiService();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.bus_stop:
                        nearByPlaces("bus_station");
                        break;
                    case R.id.market:
                        nearByPlaces("market");
                        break;
                    case R.id.restaurant:
                        nearByPlaces("restaurant");
                        break;
                    case R.id.school:
                        nearByPlaces("school");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void nearByPlaces(String placeType) {
        mMap.clear();
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, placeType);
        mService.getNearByPlaces(url)
                .enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().length; i++) {
                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                Results googlePlaces = response.body().getResults()[i];
                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlaces.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
                                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlaces.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());

                                String placeName = googlePlaces.getName();
                                String vicinity = googlePlaces.getVicinity();
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                markerOptions.title(placeName);

                                switch (placeName) {
                                    case "bus_station":
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_marker));
                                        break;
                                    case "market":
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                                        break;
                                    case "restaurant":
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                                        break;
                                    case "school":
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                                        break;
                                }


                                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String placeType) {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("loaction=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + 10000);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + placeType);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.browser_key));
        Log.d("url", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return googlePlacesUrl.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocationPermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) &&
                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mMarker != null)
            mMarker.remove();

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Current Position")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

Url that is generated:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?loaction=32.2408243,74.1493718&radius=10000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=MYAPIKEY
```

Browser Response:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Project Directory with the Classes:

[image]

Comment: I have seen similar question posted before, but none of them were relateable. Please don't down vote this. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Places SDK?

Comment: No I have enabled Places Api from the Google Cloud Platform Dashboard https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Comment: I cannot say anything without seeing the actual code and full setup. Also, there has been a lot of deprecation in places API and some of them have already been turned off. I would suggest to setup it through Google play SDK for Android. It won't take much of your time.

Comment: @Derek, I was also thinking the same but, I dont have much time as I have to Submit the Project till coming 28. Still Thanks for your Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your generated URL, there is a typo...that's it!

https//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?**loaction**=32.2408243,74.1493718&radius=10000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=MYAPIKEY

Change **loaction** to **location**.